# Isn't using a stack same as recursion?

Tags: recursion, stack

When asked for a non-recursive algorithm to solve a problem, people often use stacks but in essence aren't stacks and recursion same?. Moreover, the space complexity remains the same(asymptotically) when stacks are used to replace recursion. Is there any fundamental difference that I have failed to 
observe?

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/04/Replacing_Recursion_With_a_Stack.aspx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the exact same thing.

Using a Stack instead of using the call stack is either a work around (when a language has less stack space than the maximum your program needs to handle) or it's a optimization that might save some space since the stack frame usually take some machine words in languages that doesn't do TCO or you don't need to store the data the same way so it makes the total consumption far less even when the stack is less space efficient per item.

Not all languages need it though, In the language Racket it doesn't serve any purpose to use an explicit stack since there is no limit on the stack since other than the total memory the program has so even with non TCO calls (like tree traversal) it still would work until all memory is consumed.

In Java the stack space is configurable when you start up your program. It prefer to read recursive code so check if your language can do that before reverting to using an explicit stack.

Comment: Thank You! That was all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Your applications *stack* size is more limited than the data structure *stack*. As long as you can allocate memory dynamically (actually this time it depends on applications *heap*) you will have no problem.

Your applications stack as mentioned is more limited plus that it has the copy of each temporary local variable, function parameters, return values, stack pointers and ext. That makes its size more reduced than it seems.

Comment: That depends. Inspecting the application stack is often easier than inspecting a heap allocated stack. The machine stack is visible in pretty much every debugger when a trace is dumped; the pointer to the heap allocated stack can be corrupted.

Comment: Actually you are right. With modern editors and debuggers your case makes stronger point.

Comment: But the application stack would allow faster access because of locality .

Comment: @RAY66 That's right if the _stack_ data structure is based on dynamic memory allocations and pointer redirection, which these are the most cases. Still you can improve performance through pre-allocating required object spaces with foreseen amount which will increase the locality of references in stack.

Comment: @RAY: Locality here *should* be dwarfed by having to maintain the machine stack. (Optimizers are way better at understanding loops than understanding recursion) But as with all performance questions you don't really know until you measure with a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O complexity may be the same in some cases, but constant factors using an explicit stack are often better. Moreover, the size of the machine execution stack is often relatively small, while an explicit (heap-allocated) stack can grow much larger.

Sometimes you'll want to look for a completely different algorithm that happens to be non-recursive that will perform much better. Consider the naive fibonacci sequence algorithm:

```
int f(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
         return 1;
    }

    return f(n-2) + f(n-1);
}
```

This algorithm takes exponential time :(

The non-recursive version (actually a form of "dynamic programming" in this case) is only linear in `n`, and does not use a stack:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int fMinusOne = 1;
    int fMinusTwo = 1;
    for (int idx = 1; idx < n; ++idx)
    {
        int next = fMinusOne + fMinusTwo;
        fMinusTwo = fMinusOne;
        fMinusOne = next;
    }

    return fMinusOne;
}
```

Comment: I get your point, but my question was from a conceptual standpoint are they not one?

Comment: @RAY: That depends on the algorithm. If you simulate recursion with an explicit stack, sure. You're simulating recursion, so hopefully your simulation operates similarly. But most of the time when someone asks for a "non-recursive solution" they want a completely different algorithm.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question "ARE'NT STACKS AND RECURSION THE SAME?"

Comment: @RAY: I believe I answered your question.

Comment: Is there any way to simulate recursion without implicit or explicit use of the stack ADT?

Comment: @RAY: I don't know what "ADT" is. Recursion specifically refers to a procedure that calls itself; simulating recursion with a stack isn't actually recursion.